# My querystring parameter continuously appear

Tags: asp.net, ajax, query-string

I have a web app and i use the rewrite function for the URL. Here my sample URL:
**www.mywebsite.com/oscar**

It will bring the guest to **www.mywebsite.com/User.aspx?blk=oscar**

Everything is going fine until I realized that sometimes, I don't know why, every time my webpage do the post back, it will append the querystring into current URL. So the URL will be like this:

**www.website.com/oscar&blk=oscar&blk=oscar&blk=oscar**

anybody have the same experienced? please help me with your solution

Comment: Do you have any redirect logic that may cause something like that?

Comment: No. I use IIS 7 URL Rewrite feature to rewrite my URL and now every time i submit the form (post back), i got wrong url.

and i just realized that for the first time my page accessed, the form action show me wrong url.

Comment: my form action become like this:

<form action="oscar&blk=oscar">